# Splash screens on iPad 3

Tags: ios, ipad-3

I am developing an application that should work correctly on both iPad 2 and iPad 3. I have spash portrait and landscape screens. I use Default-Portrait.png with size 768x1004 and Default-Landscape.png with size 1024x768 for iPad2 splash screens, and Default-Portrait@2x.png with size 1536x2008 and Default-Landscape@2x.png with size 2048x1496 for iPad3. When I strat my app for the first time in iPad3 the initial splash image is first the iPad3 one ( Default-Portrait@2x.png/ Default-Landscape@2x.png)  and then it switches to the iPad2 one ( Default-Portrait.png/ Default-Landscape.png).
Does anybody know where could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

On the latest versions of Xcode, you can set the default images directly from the project settings panel. Just tap on the project on the top-left bar, then select the target and then go to the Summary tab. Scroll down and you will see the "iPad development info" panel, drag and drop there your default images (the rightmost is the retina, iPad 3 images).

Try to set the default images this way, it will automatically name them for you and I think it even resizes them for you.